# How well will my new college laptop render scenes?

Tags: rendering

Right now I have a cheap school laptop with an Intel Pentium 2117U @1.80 GHz with two cores, 8 Gb of ram, and whatever integrated graphics come with this Pentium. I like to work a lot with animation in blender, however, I tend to get a bit gungho on the models and each frame ends up taking 10 minutes to render. I have tried everything to speed up the rendering without compromising quality too much. I usually run it at 1080 100% with 130 samples.

I just purchased a new School laptop that has an I7 7500u @ 3.5 GHz (base 2.7GHz)with 2 cores, 8 Gb of ram (with intentions to plug in another chip), and an AMD Radeon R5 M430 2GB DDR3. How could you possibly beat a \$730 (probably a ripoff) computer on sale for \$550? That's how I justified it to my parents.

How well will my new college laptop render scenes?

Comment: open up some files and hit `F12`. No way for us to say for sure (unless somebody else had the same computer). It will be better, much better if the GPU is compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Better than your old one.

However, I suspect that the complexity of your scenes will increase until it, once again, matches your patience. Such is the way of technology. So I expect that for the first few months, renders will be significantly faster, but then you'll end up back at 10 minutes per frame.

Actually, 10 minutes per frame isn't too bad. Apparently the frames for Monsters University took [29 hours each](https://venturebeat.com/2013/04/24/the-making-of-pixars-latest-technological-marvel-monsters-university/) to render. So what is typically done is a workflow adjustment: you do only small parts of specific frames until you're happy with the results, and then leave things rendering overnight/overweekend.